# Finding the smallest value of the sum

Tags: number-theory, optimization, prime-factorization

> The multiplication of three natural numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ equals $2016$. What is the smallest value of $a + b + c$?

I started by a prime factorization to find that $2016 = 2^5 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 7$.
What should I do next?

Comment: Can't you  set up a Lagrangian and minimize the function $a+b+c$ subject to the equality constraint that $abc=2016$?.. intuitively, it should be the cube root of $2016$..

Comment: @KwameBrown I don't think that ensure that $a,b,c$ are natural numbers, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Oh I see you are right..

Comment: A natural guess is $\{12,12,14\}$.  Certainly, that's a good place to look.

Comment: Since multiplication scales faster than summation, we should distribute the factors "evenly", like in the example @lulu gave (i.e., a bad guess would be $2^4\cdot 3,7,3\cdot 2$, since most of the factors are given to the first number).

Comment: Hmm, my last comment was poorly worded. I mean that the three numbers should be as close to each other as possible.

Comment: Is this a contest problem?

Answer (score 3):

The minimum for natural $a,b,c$ can't be lower than the minimum for *real* $a,b,c$, which is $3\sqrt[3]{2016}\approx37.8982$. Being also a natural number, it can't be lower than 38. Can 38 be reached? Looks like you already know that, thanks to a comment by **lulu**.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider the fact that $7=2\cdot3\cdot\frac76$, then $2016=2^6\cdot3^3\cdot\frac76$, and it becomes easy to represent this number as a product of $\color\red3$ natural numbers which are as close to each other as possible:

- $a=2^{6/\color\red3}\cdot3^{3/\color\red3}=12$
- $b=2^{6/\color\red3}\cdot3^{3/\color\red3}=12$
- $c=2^{6/\color\red3}\cdot3^{3/\color\red3}\cdot\frac76=14$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_2,a_3,a_7$ denote the multiplicities of $2,3,7$ in the factorization of $a$.

You want to solve the following nonlinear integer programming problem:

$$\begin{cases}\min_\limits{a_2,a_3,a_7,b_2,b_3,b_7,c_2,c_3,c_7} 2^{a_2}3^{a_3}7^{a_7}+2^{b_2}3^{b_3}7^{b_7}+2^{c_2}3^{c_3}7^{c_7},\\
a_2,a_3,a_7,b_2,b_3,b_7,c_2,c_3,c_7\in\mathbb N_0,\\
a_2+b_2+c_2=5,\\a_3+b_3+c_3=2,\\a_7+b_7+c_7=1.\end{cases}$$

Similar linear problems are known to be NP-hard, so it is likely that there is not much better than exhaustive search for your question. (Though heuristics such as the one by @IvanNeretin can help. Most probably, Depth First Search would help too.)

There are $5$ ways to decompose $5$ so that $a_2\ge b_2\ge c_2$ (we are free to choose the order for the first decomposition), then $3$ ways to decompose $2$ and $3$ ways to decompose $1$, for a total of $45$ combinations.

By brute force:
$$
38 =2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 0 7^ 1 \\
41 =2^ 3 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 1 \\
43 =2^ 4 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 1 \\
43 =2^ 3 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 0 7^ 1 \\
44 =2^ 3 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 0 7^ 1 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
44 =2^ 3 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 0 7^ 1 \\
46 =2^ 2 3^ 0 7^ 1 +2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
46 =2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 2 3^ 0 7^ 1 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
49 =2^ 3 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 2 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 1 \\
55 =2^ 3 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 2 3^ 0 7^ 1 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
56 =2^ 5 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
56 =2^ 5 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 1 \\
56 =2^ 3 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
56 =2^ 3 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 1 \\
58 =2^ 2 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 1 \\
58 =2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 2 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 1 \\
61 =2^ 4 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
61 =2^ 4 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 0 7^ 1 \\
65 =2^ 4 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 0 7^ 1 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
68 =2^ 3 3^ 0 7^ 1 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
68 =2^ 3 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 1 \\
68 =2^ 3 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 1 3^ 0 7^ 0 \\
71 =2^ 4 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 1 \\
71 =2^ 3 3^ 0 7^ 1 +2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
91 =2^ 4 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 0 3^ 0 7^ 0 \\
94 =2^ 2 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
94 =2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 2 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
95 =2^ 3 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
98 =2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 0 7^ 0 \\
98 =2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 1 3^ 0 7^ 0 \\
106 =2^ 5 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 0 7^ 1 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
106 =2^ 5 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 0 7^ 1 \\
109 =2^ 3 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 0 3^ 0 7^ 0 \\
118 =2^ 5 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 1 \\
118 =2^ 5 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 0 3^ 0 7^ 0 \\
121 =2^ 4 3^ 0 7^ 1 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
175 =2^ 3 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 2 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
176 =2^ 3 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 1 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
176 =2^ 3 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 1 3^ 0 7^ 0 \\
181 =2^ 3 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 2 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 0 7^ 0 \\
230 =2^ 5 3^ 0 7^ 1 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
341 =2^ 4 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 1 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
343 =2^ 4 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 1 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 0 7^ 0 \\
676 =2^ 5 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 0 3^ 0 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 \\
676 =2^ 5 3^ 1 7^ 1 +2^ 0 3^ 1 7^ 0 +2^ 0 3^ 0 7^ 0 \\
$$